# Ansible & Vagrant: Get private network ip address

Tags: networking, ansible, vagrant, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a simple script to provision the machines in my Vagrant setup.

I currently have a private network set up, where each node in the Vagrant file has something like:

> node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.16.x.x"

And in my Ansible script, I originally used `{{ ansible_eth2.ipv4.address }}` to pick up the ip address in my playbook tasks.

When I recently swapped machines however, the Ansible variable was undefined because the new machine doesn't have a `eth2` network interface. On the new machine, the private ip address set in the Vagrant file appears to be assigned to the `eth1` interface.

In an attempt to get around this issue and make my Ansible playbooks hardware agnostic, I replaced all my references to `{{ ansible_eth2.ipv4.address }}` with `{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}`, but that retrieves the ip address at `eth0` (10.0.x.x in my case).

How can I set either the Vagrant file to always add the ip address to whatever network interface Ansible will use for `{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}`?

Or failing that, is there anything I can do with Ansible (or even raw shellscript), to retrieve the private ip address?

Comment: Well, what have you already tried? Because on every ansible `hostfacts` that I've ever seen, it includes the addresses of all interfaces, and thus it is trivial to jinja2 filter out the 10.0.x.y one to get the remaining one(s)

Comment: Instructions on that how to filter through the network interfaces would be helpful. For now though, I've used `node.vm.network "private_network", ip: machine_ip, bridge: "eth1: Ethernet"` in the Vagrant file to ensure that my private ip always falls on the eth1 interface. At least that's what I think that line of code is doing...

Answer (score 0):

At least one way, as there are likely several:

```yaml
  - debug:
      verbosity: 0
      msg: |
          {%- for nic in ansible_interfaces -%}
          {%- for addr in (vars["ansible_"+nic]["ipv4"] | map(attribute="address") | list)
              if not (addr | regex_search('10(\.\d+){3}')) -%}
          nic {{ nic }} := {{ addr }}
          {%- endfor -%}
          {%- endfor -%}
```